# Chamar uma variável ou método dentro de um método estático

Tags: php, laravel, escopo-de-variáveis, métodos-estáticos, scope

Olá, estou usando Laravel nessa aplicação.
Tenho um método estático chamado `get()` (Que foi criado em uma Classe que não obtive acesso) e dentro dele preciso acessar uma variável externa chamada `$routeTo`. Tentei 3 coisas e não obtive sucesso. `IS_MOBILE` é uma constante definida em outra página que está armazenada na session.

Problema:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


$routeTo = "desktop/";
if(IS_MOBILE == true){
    $routeTo = "mobile/";
}



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view( $routeTo . 'home');
});
```

Tentativa 2: **FAIL**

```
function checkingDevice(){
    $routeTo = "desktop/";
    if(IS_MOBILE == true){
        $routeTo = "mobile/";
    }
}


Route::get('/', function () {
    checkingDevice();
    return view( $routeTo . 'home');
});
```

Tentativa 3: **FAIL**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $routeTo = "desktop/";
    if(IS_MOBILE == true){
        $routeTo = "mobile/";
    }
    
    return view( $routeTo . 'home');
});
```

Acredito que seja um problema de 'contexto/escopo', onde o método `get()` não consegue a variável `$routeTo` ou o método `checkingDevice()`. Se alguém puder ajudar indicando algum material direcionado a isso já está ótimo (a documentação do laravel não fala especificamente disso).

Comment: `::get` é um `facade` e você deve fazer um middleware, dá um busca nisso.

Comment: Eu poderia criar o ```checkingDevice()``` na ```facade``` ou no ```.../Routing/Router.php```?  Ou o ideal seria criar o Middleware mesmo?

Comment: seria melhor e ideal criar um `middleware`

Comment: Você chegou a debugar IS_MOBILE com dump(IS_MOBILE) ou dd(IS_MOBILE) ? Dá uma olhada aqui >  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151268/how-to-show-different-view-page-for-mobile-device-in-laravel-5. No post tem a sugestão da biblioteca https://github.com/jenssegers/agent que é utilizado  no Laravel Jetstream

Comment: Obrigado @MarcosXavier. Acredito que resolverá meu problema. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o Laravel utiliza o padrão **MVC**.
No **MVC** quem decide qual `View` deve ser aberta é uma `Controller`. Se há regra de negócio no carregamento da `View` (como é o seu caso), não deve ser responsabilidade do arquivo de rotas cuidar disso.

Diante disso, abra uma `Controller` pra receber essa request pelo `Routes`, e trate o carregamento da view dentro dela.

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
 
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for a given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', [
            'user' => User::findOrFail($id)
        ]);
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers

Answer (score 0):

Você até pode utilizar variáveis de fora da função, mas o problema que está ocorrendo não é por isso.

A constante `IS_MOBILE` não pode ser definida na sessão como você mencionou.  O primeiro problema seria esse. Mesmo que você recupere este valor da sessão, isso não seria possível fazer diretamente no arquivo de rotas como tentou, apenas seria recuperável de dentro da própria action, usando a `Request` do Laravel, porque nesse contexto, somente ali a sessão estaria carregada. Tudo fora de uma action (neste caso, sua function dentro do `Route::get()` nesse arquivo é chamado ainda na inicialização do Laravel, o que não te garante que a sessão esteja devidamente carregada.

Supondo que este valor realmente esteja na sessão, então...

**Solução:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
   $routeTo = "desktop/";
    if($request->session('IS_MOBILE')) {
        $routeTo = "mobile/";
    }

    return view( $routeTo . 'home');
});
```

Apesar disso, recomendo que utilize [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers) para colocar este tipo de regra e que evite usar funções anônimas no próprio arquivo de rotas do Laravel, pois isso **impede a otimização das rotas feita pelo Laravel**, causando queda de performance, muitas vezes significativas.

---

Agora, respondendo a sua dúvida sobre variáveis fora do escopo, você pode sim trazer variáveis de fora pra dentro de uma função. Você pode usar o `use`:

**Exemplo**:

```
$foo = '123';

Route::get('/my-route', function () use ($foo) {
// $foo aqui estaria disponível 
});
```

A sua tentativa 2, mesmo que a constante estivesse ok, não funcionaria, pois a variável `$routeTo` definida dentro da função `checkingDevice()` só existirá dentro dessa mesma função. Uma solução seria usar o `return` e utilizar o retorno da função.